# Can I pass an array of arrays of String (String[][]) to a function in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor

I've got a constructor like this:

```
public Cat(String name, String[][] friendsOfFriendsNames){...}
```

And I would like to create a new `Cat` like this:

```
Cat cat = new Cat("Maurycy", {{"Adam", "Greta"}, {"Jurek", "Tyrmand"}});
```

However I am getting `Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)` error in Eclipse.

It turns out that I can introduce a new variable like `friendsOfFriendsNames` and then pass it to the constructor. Eclipse doesn't raise any error then.

```
String[][] friendsOfFriendsNames = {{"Adam", "Greta"}, {"Jurek", "Tyrmand"}};

Cat cat = new Cat("Maurycy", friendsOfFriendsNames);
```

Why is it so? Is it possible to pass `{{"Adam", "Greta"}, {"Jurek", "Tyrmand"}}` directly to the constructor? If so, how should I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to tell Java what type of array it is, e.g.

```
Cat cat = new Cat("Maurycy", new String[][]{{"Adam", "Greta"}, {"Jurek", "Tyrmand"}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
new String[][]{{"Adam", "Greta"}, {"Jurek", "Tyrmand"}}
```